# How to grant a Web App that uses Azure ADB2C for authentication access to a M365 environment via Microsoft Graph?

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-b2c

I have a M365 Environment with Azure AD.

I have created an Azure AD B2C tenant from within Azure AD.

I have registered two applications in the Azure AD B2C Tenant

- `MyWebAppAPI` (with API Scopes exposed)
- `MyWebApp` (with API permissions granted to `MyWebAppAPI`'s exposed scopes)

I have an existing Node.js/Express Web App which uses Azure AD B2C for authentication/authorisation.

It runs server side code, and is therefore a 'çonfidential client', not a single page app.

I have `Sign In`, `Sign Out` and `Profile Edit` user flows configured.

I have also added the ability for users from a single Azure AD tenant to sign in (by adding that tenant as an Identity Provider).

Everything is working fine - users of both types can sign in, call an API endpoint, and sign out.

I would like to add the ability for both types of users, ie:

- EXTERNAL users who are signing in with Azure ADB2C 'local' accounts
- INTERNAL users who are signing in with their Azure AD accounts

to, in different capacities, interact with the Microsoft 365 environment via the Graph API.

For example:

- EXTERNAL users could submit form data to locations in M365 (lists, libraries, emails, approval flows etc).
- INTERNAL users could submit their own form data and also read data from various locations in M365.

There is [a FAQ question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/faq?tabs=app-reg-ga#can-i-use-azure-ad-b2c-to-provide-social-login--facebook-and-google---into-microsoft-365-) which seems to infer this is not possible at all:

> Azure AD B2C can't be used to authenticate users for Microsoft 365. Azure AD is Microsoft's solution for managing employee access to SaaS apps and it has features designed for this purpose such as licensing and Conditional Access. Azure AD B2C provides an identity and access management platform for building web and mobile applications. When Azure AD B2C is configured to federate to an Azure AD tenant, the Azure AD tenant manages employee access to applications that rely on Azure AD B2C.

However, I still need the functionality and therefore need to make it happen somehow (in a safe way).

I don't think the idea is totally preposterous, as Microsoft's own demo of Azure AD B2C ([WoodGrove Groceries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/overview#example-woodgrove-groceries)) does have three 'login scenarios':

- Individual Customers (using B2C - personal account)
- Business Customers (using B2C - work or school account)
- Business Partners (using B2B)

So they are atleast aware that there is a need for different user groups to be able to access the same application and data (albeit in different ways).

My question is:

What approach should I use to achieve the desired functionality in the safest way possible?

There must be a way to do it, I just can't figure out how.

I'm also sure there must be good and bad ways to do it, and I'd like to know the good ways.

Answer (score 1):

There is a detailed example from Microsoft provided in this [github](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/B2C-Token-Includes-AzureAD-BearerToken)

## Include an Azure AD access token through a B2C token, as part of a B2C Sign In

### Scenario

This sample solution demonstrates how to sign in through a B2C policy to a federated identity provider, Azure AD in this case, and include the original identity provider token, an Azure AD bearer token, as a claim in the B2C token.  It also shows how to call the Graph API of the users’ home Azure AD tenant using the issued Azure AD Bearer token.  For reference, similar capability can be achieved to receive the original identity provider’s id token [using the built-in B2C user flows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/idp-pass-through-user-flow).

### Prerequisites

- To configure this solution, you will need to use Azure AD B2C Custom policies that use the Azure AD B2C Identity Experience Framework.  [Review the getting started with custom B2C applications](https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom?tabs=applications).
- In the getting started documentation, it references the B2C starter pack of advanced policies – a set of edited versions of the starter pack base, extension and signUpsignIn policy files, are included in this sample, that includes the updates that enable the issuance of the Azure AD identity provider access token.
- We also recommend using [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and installing the [Azure AD B2C extension for editing Custom policies](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AzureADB2CTools.aadb2c), as there are many functions in this extension that are designed to enhance the configuration experience.

### Instructions

#### Step 1: Register a Multi-tenant application - this allows users from Azure AD tenants to sign-in to your B2C tenant

1. From the Azure AD B2C portal, select App registration, create a friendly name for the app, and select the "Accounts in any organizational directory…" under the Supported Account Types.  By selecting this application option, it makes the application type to be a [Multi-tenant application](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant), thus making it available to Azure AD tenants.
2. The reply url (redirect URI) should be your b2c tenant instance’s reply url  (replace “your-B2C-tenant-name” with your tenant’s name.).
   `https://your-B2C-tenant-name.b2clogin.com/your-B2C-tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp`
3. Select Register.  After the application is successfully created, copy down the Application (client) id – which will be used in the B2C policy file (see below)
4. Next select, select API Permission, and select Add Permission.  Select Microsoft Graph and select Delegated Permissions.
5. Then Select openid and user.read. Select the “Add Permissions” button to save your configuration.

At this point, you should have both User.Read and openid selected under Microsoft Graph.

Please note that other delegated permissions could have been selected however, some may need Admin consent before the user will be able to sign into your application. A best practice is to request the minimum permissions needed by your application.  If you find that additional permissions are needed, you can add them later; users and administrators may need to re-consent to the new permissions.

#### Step 2: Update the B2C Policy Permissions and Client Secret

A client Secret associated with this application, must be created – select either 1 or 2 year expiration (select Never for testing purposes only).

Copy the client secret – in the next steps, we will need to store the value in a B2C policy key location, and reference the key location from within the Azure AD technical profile in the B2C policy file.

#### Step 3: Add the Application Secret to the Identity Experience Framework Policy Key

Create a B2C policy key (under the Identity Experience Framework blade).  Select Manual for the Option, create a name (we will reference this policyKeyName in the next step) and enter the client secret value from the previous step.

#### Step 4: Update the AzureADProfile_issueAADToken technical profile in the B2C policy file

The application (client ID) and the permissions must be updated in the AzureAD technical profile in your B2C policy file.   First update the values for the client_id and the IdTokenAudience in the policy file.

Update the Scope value to equal the permissions that you configured for your.  This should be openid and user.read.   Note: for mutliple scopes, each scope value should be separated by a space.
openid user.read

#### Step 5: First Sign In experience for users

- During the first-time user logon from an Azure AD tenant, users will be able to consent to Microsoft Graph permissions if the requested permissions do not require administrator consent.
- Administrators can consent on behalf of all users in their organization – after this consent, users will not see request for consent.
- Some permissions require the company administrator’s consent; therefore users are not authorized to consent individually.  In this case, users will be blocked from sign in until the company administrator logons to the app and consents on behalf of all users in their organization.

*Figure 1: User cannot logon nor consent to an app requesting privileged permissions*

#### Step 6: Call the Graph API using the access token

Upon successful user sign on, the original Azure AD idp access token will  be part of the B2C token.  This idp access token can be used to access the users’ home Azure AD tenant’s Graph API (with the scope of Directory.Read)   For example:

The idp access_token, is base64 encoded and can be viewed:

Calls to the Microsoft Graph Call can now be made, using this idp access token in the authorization header.
Example:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/chad@deployit.info
Authorization:  eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Qi……. DUxWmJUbktFZFc1`

Comment: Thank you, re: the 1st link:  '...similar capability can be achieved to receive the original identity provider’s id token using [the built-in B2C user flows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/idp-pass-through-user-flow)' - it is easy to go to `User Flow` > `Application Claims` and check `Identity Provider Access Token`.  Now that I have `idp_access_token`, how do I use it to access the Azure AD users M365 environment via Graph API?  If I go to my `App Registration` > `API Permissions` > `Add a permission`,  there is no option to select Graph API of original tenant.

Comment: I will keep researching, but just thought I would ask, in case it is an easy answer (i'm also running into questions like:  1)  Should I save `idp_access_token` in `req.session` so that I can use it as the bearer token when making calls to Graph API?  2)  Is msal-node automatically handling the refresh tokens for the `idp_access_token`?  3)  Where should I be defining the scopes on requests to Azure AD M365?  etc).

Comment: The Graph API is not tenant specific. The access token determines the tenant the Graph API will operate. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-get-started?tabs=app-reg-ga
You may want to have two copies of your application; one registered in Azure AD B2C that acquires the access token  and another registered in Azure AD to which authenticated users are redirected and which is setup with delegated permissions. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-connect-app-access-microsoft-graph-as-user-javascript?tabs=azure-resource-explorer

Comment: In the Azure AD B2C `API permissions` GUI, Graph API _delegated permissions_ are only available for `offline_access` and `openid`.  When I add _application permissions_ for `User.ReadWrite.All` and `Directory.ReadWrite.All` (with Admin Consent granted), and use the `idp_access_token` as the `Bearer` token in the headers of a request to the Graph API, eg 
 `axios.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/info@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com', options)`, i get a 403 error, `ERR_BAD_REQUEST`.

Comment: When I decode the `idp_access_token` at https://jwt.ms, the scopes value (`scp`) has this value `openid profile email` - so, on top of whatever else is not working, it doesn't look like the required scopes are being passed through to the `idp_access_token`.

Comment: I got a response by going to `Azure AD B2C` > `Identity Providers` > `OpenID Connect` and in the `Scope` field, I changed the value from this: `openid profile` to this: `openid profile User.ReadWrite.All Directory.ReadWrite.All`.  So now my call to the Graph API gets a response, but I don't know _how_ its doing what its doing, and my instinct tells me whatever I've given it access to do is too powerful.